# Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, error-handling, uuid

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. The Ubuntu setup instructed me to restart the system. After I restarted it automatically boots into Windows. I used easyBCD to add the entry of Ubuntu in boot-loader. Now that when I try to boot in Ubuntu I am getting the grub screen. I don't know what to do now as I am newbie to this. Also I think there is some problem with my hard disk as I am not even able to boot into Windows 10. I checked some online resources where they instructed the steps I performed. The steps are shown here:

[image]

to boot back into Ubuntu successfully. It would be of great help if anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance.